# Java Array Manipulation and Bugfixing

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm working my way through a java learning book and at the moment I'm learning about arrays and vectors. I've been doing ok up until now I've been stuck on this question for ages and have no idea how to tackle it, my head is about to explode!

The questions for this certain program I have to tackle are:

1. Elementary error checking is introduced, specifically check that the array Tokens has two elements, if there is a problem with the format of the data inform the user but carry on accepting input.
2. It will accept input of either

   - quit
   - put name mark
   - get name

   The quit scenario works as before, the second scenario stores the student and their mark at the next
   available array index; whilst get just returns the mark of any student who matched to the name ( there
   may be more than one such student, there many be none).
3. The program reads in the mark as an integer not a String (you can find examples of the structure you
   need by searching for Integer.parseInt on Google).
4. Upon typing quit, the mean mark, and the highest mark are also displayed.

The java code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String b;
        String student[] = new String[50];
        String mark[] = new String[50];
        int i = 0;
        while ((b = s.nextLine()) != null) {
            if (b.equals("quit")) break;
            String Tokens[] = b.split(' ');
            // System.out.println(Tokens[0] + ' ' + Tokens[1]);
            student[i] = Tokens[0];
            mark[i] = Tokens[1];
            i++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(student[j] + ' ' + mark[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

It also throws out on error on this line:

```
String Tokens[] = b.split(' ');
```

Comment: use Eclipse. very popular java ide. it will highlight the errors and help with API.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Multi-part questions are awkward because there are multiple answers that collectively make up a solution while only one can be marked as correct. Consider asking multiple, separate questions: first one about the compiler error you're getting. Then try to solve `(a)` and ask another question if you can't figure it out. Then try to solve `(b)` and post if you can't figure that out, etc.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
b.split("\\s+");
```

to split on whitespaces.
This will cause any number of consecutive spaces to split your string into tokens as the split() method in java is constructed to be used with regular expressions anyway

Comment: Can you also explain what the difference is? OP might not know.

Comment: should be fine now :)

Comment: It is. If you would also add the note, that you're using a *String* and not a *char* like OP, then it will be even better :). Here is the corresponding JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29.

Answer (score 0):

I would've written it like this (tried it on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ODJXiR)):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayInput {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String b;
            String[] student = new String[50]; // changed here
            String[] mark = new String[50];  // Changed here
            int i = 0;
            b = s.nextLine(); // Get the next line here first
            while (b != null) { // Evalaute b as for while loop here
                if (b.equals("quit")) break;
                String[] Tokens = b.split(" "); // Changed to use " ", not ' '
                // System.out.println(Tokens[0] + ' ' + Tokens[1]);
                student[i] = Tokens[0];
                mark[i] = Tokens[1];
                i++;
                b = s.nextLine(); // get the next line here before looping again.
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(student[j] + ' ' + mark[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Scanner`class has a method called `hasNext()` which you can use quite helpfully for the `while()` loops. If you use that the following snippet is improved:

```
// b = s.nextLine() not needed anymore
while(s.hasNext()){
...
...
...
 }
```

Comment: Yes? You also would use `while ((b = s.nextLine()) != null)` with a Scanner? You know, that this will cause in an Exception, right?

Comment: The proper way of looping with a `Scanner` is `while(scanner.hasNext...())` (`...` like  *Line*, *Int* etc.). Scanner doesn't return `null`, so if you would read from something that could end, like a file, then your current  loop will cause an Exception.